# Trying to get subdomains working on my server

Tags: apache, hosting, subdomain, virtualhost

I'm trying to get subdomains working for a web app that i'm working on. I followed this tut http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter/ and I was able to get it working locally by adding my urls to my /etc/hosts file and then adding the following to my httpd.config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/snapGiftApp"  
    ServerName snapgiftapp.com  
    ServerAlias snapgiftapp.com  

    <Directory "/Users/username/Sites/snapGiftApp">  
        Options -Indexes  
        Options FollowSymLinks  
        AllowOverride All  
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>  

<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/snapGiftApp"  
    ServerName snapgiftapp.com  
    ServerAlias *.snapgiftapp.com  

    <Directory "/Users/username/Sites/snapGiftApp">  
        Options -Indexes  
        Options FollowSymLinks  
        AllowOverride All  
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm now trying to get it working on my server and i'm unable to get the subdomain piece working. If you go to http://snapgiftapp.com, you see the landing page just fine. If you go to any http://subdomain.snapgiftapp.com, you see an error page.

I've added a wildcard subdomain to my dns and i've added the following to my httpd.config file and i'm still getting an error when viewing http://subdomain.snapgiftapp.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/snapgift"  
    ServerName snapgiftapp.com  
    ServerAlias snapgiftapp.com  

    <Directory "/home/snapgift">  
        Options -Indexes  
        Options FollowSymLinks  
        AllowOverride All  
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>  

<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "/home/snapgift"  
    ServerName snapgiftapp.com  
    ServerAlias *.snapgiftapp.com  

    <Directory "/home/snapgift">  
        Options -Indexes  
        Options FollowSymLinks  
        AllowOverride All  
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong on the server that this is not working? Do I need to provide the full path for the directory? i.e. /var/www/etc/etc.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I had my wildcard dns set on the domain name and not on the actual host.